# Edit .htaccess with PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mapping, dns, edit

I have a .htaccess that maps a domain to a folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect mapped domain
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} joshblease.uk.to
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !gme-index/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ gme-index/$1 [L]
```

Is there any way to edit/add extra domain maps to the file using PHP?

Simply, I want to get the contents of the .htaccess file and add to them using a PHP script.

Comment: Nooooooooooooooo never edit .htaccess with PHP, you're just asking for security issues...

Comment: @Cyclone: If it's done properly it's not a security risk.

Comment: Nothing yet and i've looked around for quite a while, sorry if its a lot. I'm a novice developer. Its like cpanel and how http redirects are added with that.

Comment: Just to throw this out there: presuming that your PHP script is a web script, letting a web script update the web server configuration (which is what .htaccess is) is a potential security disaster.  Sometimes it might not be avoidable, but tread with great care.  And yes, what have you tried?

Comment: If you are not experienced with that, you should rather set up a `RewriteMap` which is easier to append to without syntax woes.

Comment: @ConradShultz: I don't think you can compare those. Editing the *real* config files would require root privileges while .htaccess files are usually owned by a user accessible by the PHP scripts anyway. So a malicious/bugged script could edit them anyway.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Sure, if it's not based on any user input whatsoever, or if it's filtered securely, and your code is sound...but otherwise you may find yourself opening a rather large security hole.

Comment: If its easier, I want to point domains to my ip and map them to different folders but with a web "control panel"

Comment: Question is why do you want to do that? .htaccess file should be not be edited many times a day.

Comment: I want different domains mapped to different folders and I can't add addon domains as my hosting only allows a few. If not .htaccess, then is there another way of doing this?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: The extent to which .htaccess can screw things up is determined in large part by other variables (e.g. AllowOverride). We don't know how that's set up in this case.  Further, my .htaccess files are explicitly non-writable by Apache so they *can't* be edited by a malicious script for that reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As suggested in one of the comments above it is better to use [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) for your case here rather than trying to edit .htaccess from PHP code directly. Here is a sample how to use it:

1. Add following line to your httpd.conf file:

   ```
   RewriteMap domainMap txt://path/to/domain-dir.txt
   ```
2. Create a text file as `/path/to/domain-dir.txt` like this:

   ```
   sub1 /subdir1
   sub2 /foodir2
   foo /bar
   ```
3. Add these line in your .htaccess file:

   ```
   Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^$ ${domainMap:%1} [L,R]
   ```

Effectively all this means is to have these redirects in place:

- `sub1.domain.com/ => sub1.domain.com/subdir1`
- `sub2.domain.com/ => sub2.domain.com/foodir2`
- `foo.domain.com/  => foo.domain.com/bar`

**Advantage:** With this setup in place, you can edit or recreate the file `/path/to/domain-dir.txt` as much as you want from your php code without opening a huge security hole be allowing php code o edit .htaccess directly.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without the httpd.conf file? I'm on shared hosting.

Comment: Unfortunately no because `RewriteMap` directive only goes into httpd.conf file. However it will be just **one time** change in httpd.conf.

Answer (score 4):

This could work for your situation:

Ammend the .htaccess to look the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect mapped domain
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} joshblease.uk.to
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !gme-index/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ gme-index/$1 [L]

###CUSTOM RULES###
```

php script assuming $rules holds the new generated rules to be ammended;

```
$htaccess = file_get_contents('/path/to/.htaccess');
$htaccess = str_replace('###CUSTOM RULES###', $rules."\n###CUSTOM RULES###", $htaccess);
file_put_contents('/path/to/.htaccess', $htaccess);
```

example above is theory and has not been tested, would be dependant upon .htaccess privledges and permissions of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following htaccess to map any domain other than `maindomain.com` to a folder that has the same name as the domain-name.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !maindomain.com
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L]
```

alternatively; to map the folder to the domainname without the ltd.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !maindomain.com
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]*)
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L]
```

Not exactly what you wanted, but it might work for you, and doesn't need any php.