# RewriteRule required for URL's with query parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I wish to rewrite and 301 redirect a URL with query parameter like the below:-

```
domain.com/link.asp?StockNo=601-0287
```

to something such as the below:-

```
domain.com/Product-Name
```

The stock number will be different for many URL's as will the Product-Name for each.

There is not many URL's to do so manually writing would not be an issue...

Something such as the below is not working:-

```
RewriteRule ^link.asp/?StockNo=601-0287$ /Product-Name/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this would be the kind of desired rules.

What would be the best way to handle these rewrites?

Would a RewriteCond be required? I'm presuming {QUERY_STRING} wouldn't be required because the Product-Name does not match the query string?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match REQUEST_URI and QUERY_STRING together you need to use `%{THE_REQUEST}`

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+link\.asp\?StockNo=[^\s]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Product-Name/? [R=302,L]
```

**EDIT:** To handle specific stocks numbers:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+link\.asp\?StockNo=601-0287 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Product-A/? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+link\.asp\?StockNo=601-0293 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Product-B/? [R=302,L]
```

If you have too many of these stocks to rewrite then I would strongly recommend using RewriteMap to you. See this answer for more details: [Edit .htaccess with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899805/edit-htaccess-with-php/8901022#8901022)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Almost so nearly there - It's appending the URL with the query string (i.e: `domain.com/Product-Name/?StockNo=601-0287`). Everything from the `?` is not required. Is there a modification to your answer that would remove the query string from the URL? Thanks for such a prompt answer.

Comment: Can you try in a different browser since this `?` in the `/Product-Name/%1?` would strip down query from redirected URL.

Comment: Same occurred in different browser (cache was cleared just to be sure).

Comment: I also tested in my Apache and redirected URL came out to be: `/Product-Name/601-0287` so can't think of a reason why it is different for you. Can you pls post your latest .htaccess (with this change) to your question.

Comment: If that is the outcome for you, please could you modify it to remove the number after `Product-Name/`? It doesn't need any of the query string at the end of the URL. Thanks. If I can figure out how to initialise the chat window with you, I will be able to show you the .htaccess and a live URL where this is happening :) Thanks.

Comment: Alright I edited to make it `/Product-Name/` can you try it now.

Comment: That's done it, working perfectly now. Thanks very much. Great work! :)

Comment: Oh wait, it's redirecting all stock numbers to the same page. (For example: `link.asp/?StockNo=601-0293` also goes to the same Product-Name).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30848/discussion-between-geoff-jackson-and-anubhava)

Comment: Yes it will be redirecting to literal string `/Product-Name/` since .htaccess rules don't know how to translate to names from StockNo. Precisely that's why I included StockNo in the URL earlier.

Comment: Revised edit to handle individual stock numbers to different products works perfectly. Thanks. Super answer.